# netbeans: how to debug a POST request (PHP)

Tags: php, netbeans

I am trying to get a hang of netbeans (PHP) with xdebug.

I have found out the way to do a debug is usually set the URL in netbeans, e.g.

```
http://localhost/muster/index.php?module=Wind&Action=Test
```

then hit the debug button, but what do I do to debug a POST request? e.g.

there is a javascript function in a .js file which calls a php file with POST, it is like this:

```
    new Ajax.Request(
            'index.php',
            {
                    queue: {position: 'end', scope: 'command'},
                    method: 'post',
                    postBody: "module=Wine&action=WineAjax&return_id="+id,
                    onComplete: function(response)
                    { ....
```

How do I set the URL to start the debugging?

Many thanks for any input!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a parameter that tells xdebug that a debugger is listening. When you initiate the debug after having supplied the url `http://localhost/muster/index.php?module=Wind&Action=Test`, Netbeans adds the query parameter XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug to the url. This is what triggers xdebug to connect to the IDE.

To get the same effect from a POST request, you need to add the query parameter to your POST data:

```
postBody: "module=Wine&action=WineAjax&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug&return_id="+id
```

This will trigger xdebug to connect to Netbeans.

Comment: I think I remember doing it. However, where do I put http://localhost/muster/index.php

Comment: Where to add query parameter to post data?

Answer (score 0):

Except to pass XDEBUG_SESSION_START as a POST/GET parameter,  Cookie is also one alternative option. You can use browser extension which allow you to active debug by click button, and then cookie  named "XDEBUG_SESSION" is set in browse automatically. This way is suit for post request, you do not need to add parameter manually.

**Chrome**:
  https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaac.
**Firefox**:https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/.