# Can I get Netbeans 7.3 to debug a PHP script in response to a JSON request?

Tags: javascript, php, json, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1, and usually I can successfully debug PHP files using Xdebug. However, that's only if my site project is structured in such a way that the site is generated from PHP code right off the bat.

Right now I have a site which is mostly made from HTML files. The HTML static, not generated by PHP. The only PHP file in the project is called `phphandler.php`. I need to debug that PHP file, but it only runs in response to a Javascript/jQuery call from within the HTML files that looks like this:

```
$.post(siteURL + 'jsonhandler.php', {
                JSON: JSON.stringify(data)
            }, processResult, "json");
```

On the PHP side, it processes the JSON request from `$_POST`

```
$Array = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['JSON']), true);
```

When I run the debugger from within JSON, it opens Chrome and loads my site, starting with `index.html`, but the debugger never opens `jsonhandler.php`. I can go through all the links and navigate through my site, and it will get all the JSON data it needs from `jsonhandler.php`, but the debugger remains uninvolved.

Can I debug through `jsonhandler.php` when the Javascript sends it a request via `$_POST`, and if so, how?

---

**Update:** I've discovered that I can debug `jsonhandler.php` using the `Debug File` function, but this has serious drawbacks, namely that I can't create a situation in which `jsonhandler.php` is receiving JSON data as constructed by the rest of the site. I can manually force in some hand made test JSON data, but then that seriously inhibits my ability to discover what the system is doing as a whole.

Anyway, for me this is another indicator that the debugging environment is configured correctly, it's just a matter of if and how the debugger can listen for the right events.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is putting break points. Try putting breakpoints to the PHP code that receives the request (or that you want to debug) in the jsonhanler.php file and them run in debug mode, navigate through your site and send the request, the debugger should open Netbeans and take you to the line where you left the breakpoint. From there you can now go line by line or jump into functions.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, adding breakpoints did not change the circumstances in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing the $Array received in the php file by print_r($Array) followed by an exit() which might stop the process in the php file and show you the result coming in the php file. This might allow you to see as to what the php file is getting when it is loaded in the $Array. Or else if its an ajax request you can print the response in the console by console.log(response). I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This is a viable approach to debugging in general, but it doesn't actually address the question, which is specifically how to get Netbeans to activate its debugger under the conditions specified.

Answer (score 0):

I recently responded to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19636910/212076

Basically, you need to add a query parameter within your JSON to trigger the debugger:

```
XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

If the data is being obtained directly from a HTML Form, then include a hidden field like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="XDEBUG_SESSION_START" value="netbeans-xdebug" />
```